# Ошибка при парсинге PYTHON

Tags: python, парсер

Я написал скрипт, который в цикле постоянно парсит сайт, получая из него новые добавленные данные.
Через некоторое время работы скрипт возвращает такую ошибку:

> `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера>`

Comment: Это нормально, добавляйте в код обработку этой ошибки

Comment: Python: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060

Comment: Владельцы сайтов обычно не хотят чтобы их парсили. Поэтому многие сайты имеют защиту и блокируют парсеры как только их заметят.

Answer (score 2):

Сайт, скорее всего, просто отклоняет запрос. Если это действительно так, чтобы такого не происходило, можно:

1. увеличить таймаут между запросами
2. для каждого запроса использовать новый User-Agent (поищите в интернете списки юзерагентов или используйте библиотеку fake_useragent - https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)
3. использовать прокси

Лучше всего, совместите несколько пунктов.